# Retroactively download a history of all URLs I have visited in Chrome

Tags: chrome, url, history

I spend a vast amount of time browsing the internet and often have vague memories of things I would like to revisit that I know I have looked at in the past. I have just begun to use [Flamory](https://flamory.com/) and am considering [Fetching.io](http://fetching.io/) once I have the money to pay for it.

However, I want to retroactively reclaim at least a list of URLs I have visited with Chrome. I have used the same Google account and Chrome for all my web browsing for at least 5 years. I am essentially wondering if Google might retain a universal list of visited URLs, if not more, that could be downloaded by the user. Else, a third-party application that accomplishes something along the same line.

Comment: Have you ever deleted your history in Chrome? Or used something like CCleaner that does that for you?